# Why does my Apple watch 3 have to be hard reset every week to avoid catastrophic battery loss?

Tags: battery, apple-watch

My (wife's) series 3 Apple watch (non-cellular, 38mm) is a little over 2 years old and in the last few weeks has started exhibiting terrible battery performance - it will go from full charge to totally flat in half a day even with minimal use and any power saving options available.

We've determined that resetting the watch - fully unpairing and repairing - fixes the problem so a full day's use can be achieved but after about a week, the problem comes back.

Re-linking the watch to the phone is quite time-consuming so is there a known reason for this problem and any way to fix it? The watch is running the latest supported OS and shows battery health is above the 80% threshold at which Apple recommend replacement.

*This other question ([watchOS battery drains quickly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381964/watchos-battery-drains-quickly)) may seem similar but is about general poor battery performance - in my case performance suddenly degrades and re-pairing the device temporarily address it, which was not their experience*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [watchOS battery drains quickly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381964/watchos-battery-drains-quickly)

Comment: @fsb no. That is about constant poor battery life, my question is about sudden, dramatic loss of performance. The OP explicitly states that resetting/repairing their watch made no difference

Comment: What build / version is the watchOS? Latest isn’t helpful even in the moment as some people have beta versions and over time, it’s hard to know what was latest years later.